# UnityContainer.ResolveAll(Type) Autofac equivalent

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, autofac

UnityContainer has UnityContainer.ResolveAll(Type t)

Is there an Autofac equivalent?

Or is my only option to use reflection and the given Type t to somehow call Autofac's

`Resolve<T>()`

?

Answer (score 0):

```
Resolve<IEnumerable<T>>()
```